# Converting an array of unsigned shorts, to an array of unsigned chars

Tags: c++, c, arrays, casting

I can't seem to work out what is happening here. I have the following alert icon;

```
K_USHORT usaAlertIcon[16] = { 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0180, 0x03C0, 0x03C0, 0x0660, 0x0660, 0x0E70, 0x0E70, 0x1E78, 0x3E7C, 0x3FFC, 0x7E7E, 0x7E7E, 0xFFFF, 0x0000 };
```

Now, I want to use it in my code, that considers the array to be in 8 bit data (unsigned char);

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GraphicsDriver::Stamp(DrawStamp_t *pstStamp_)
{
    K_USHORT usRow;
    K_USHORT usCol;
    K_USHORT usShift;
    K_USHORT usIndex;
    DrawPoint_t stPoint;

    usIndex = 0;
    for (usRow = pstStamp_->usY; usRow < (pstStamp_->usY + pstStamp_->usHeight); usRow++)
    {
        usShift = 0x80;
        for (usCol = pstStamp_->usX; usCol < (pstStamp_->usX + pstStamp_->usWidth); usCol++)
        {
            // If the packed bit in the bitmap is a "1", draw the color.
            if (pstStamp_->pucData[usIndex] & usShift)
            {
                stPoint.usX = usCol;
                stPoint.usY = usRow;
                stPoint.uColor = pstStamp_->uColor;
                DrawPixel(&stPoint);
            }
            // Stamps are opaque, don't fill in the BG

            // Shift to the next bit in the field
            usShift >>= 1;

            // Rollover - next bit in the bitmap.
            // This obviously works best for stamps that are multiples of 8x8
            if (usShift == 0)
            {
                usShift = 0x80;
                usIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When assigning the array to the data structure to be sent through to this function, I cast it as;

```
stStamp.pucData = (K_UCHAR*)usaAlertIcon;
```

However, when I do this, it seems to flip the bytes. It draws the left half first, then the right half; so it has cut the image down the middle, and swapped the left piece for the right piece.

As a sanity check, if I explicitly split up the array myself;

```
K_UCHAR ucaAlertIcon[32] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x06, 0x60, 0x06, 0x60, 0x0E, 0x70, 0x0E, 0x70, 0x1E, 0x78, 0x3E, 0x7C, 0x3F, 0xFC, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

All works as expected.

Can someone explain why these bytes seem to be flipping when I do a type cast?

Comment: Are you aware of [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @Joe: bah! you beat me to it :)

Comment: Gee, I had a feeling it was endianness. Seems odd that the 16 bit array is not stored in memory the same as the 8 bit array when split.

Comment: 16 bits is typically the first size where endianness becomes an issue. Thats why UTF-16 has a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain why these bytes seem to be flipping when I do a type cast?

Endianness. You are apparently on a little-endian machine, that means the byte at the lowest address is the least significant byte. You need to convert the `unsigned short` values to big-endian format, `htons` for example does that.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
```

You can of course do it yourself too,

```
array[i] = (array[i] << 8) | (array[i] >> 8);
```

Comment: ...and of course, that code would totally break on a big-endian machine. htons() is a safer alternative (though perhaps slower). Of course this begs the question: why was the original data stored as 16 bits anyway?